# Queue is needed when I use aws api gateway/lambda as web server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, queue

I am learning Apache Kafka as Queue. 
I can understand queue is needed when I run web server not to drop burst traffic.
Queue can help not to drop data for rush hours.
Unless using Queue, the only thing I can do is to put more server as much as rush hour traffic.
Is it right?

If it is right,
Assume that, I use aws api gateway + lambda for web server.
aws lambda can be auto scale. So my lambda web server never drop burst traffic. It means Queue such as Kafka is not needed in this case ?

Surely if I need any pub/sub architecture, Kafka is needed.

Is it right what I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Gateway is typically used for cases where you care about the result of the API call and want to do something with the response. In this case, you need to wait for the Lambda function to finish and return the result so it can be passed back to the client. You don't need a queue because Lambda will scale out and add processes for each request. The limit would be the 10,000 requests per second of API Gateway, or the capacity of any downstream systems like a database.

Kafka is designed for real-time data streaming cases; things where you want to process data immediately, such as transcribing video. It is different than pub/sub. Consumers request data from Kafka. If the process requires merging data from multiple input sources on an on-going basis, then Kafka is a good fit. To say this another way, if the size of the input has no upper bound, stream processing is a good choice. A similar service that is available on AWS is Amazon Kinesis.

Pub/sub (such as Amazon SNS, which can easily trigger Lambda functions) is better for use cases where the size of the input, or the size of a useful batch, can be easily defined, but where data should still be processed near real-time. In a pub/sub system, events are published to subscribers rather than subscribers requesting them.

Another option is a queue like Amazon SQS, which can be useful if there is a bottleneck somewhere else in the system, such as database write capacity, or a Lambda concurrency limit. In this architecture, consumers request items from the queue when they are ready to process them, so it is better for use-cases where results are not immediately required.